# Angular/Typescript - Array of Objects of another Array Error

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

We got an array "food/essen" which consists of 10 objects.

Foodplan is an Array of  8 Objects of the Array "Food" AND an ID "Weeknumber".

The Problem is, that in our web-app the program does not print the details, but it recognizes its 8  objects.

```
class Essen {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    preis: number;
    art: string;
}

class Essensplan {
    Wochennummer: number;
    EssenProWoche: number[] = new Array(5);

"essen": [
{
  "id": 11,
  "name": "Kabeljaufilet",
  "preis": 3.55,
  "art": "mit Fisch"
},

"essensplan": [
{
  "Wochennummer": 1,
   "EssenProWoche": [
    11,
    12, 
    13
  ] 
},
```

**essensplan.service.ts**

```
/** GET ESSENSPLAN FROM THE SERVER */
getEssensplan(): Observable<Essensplan[]> {
    return this.http.get<Essensplan[]>(this.essensplanUrl)
        .pipe(
            tap(essensplanUrl => this.log('fetched essensplan')),
            catchError(this.handleError('getEssensplan', []))
        );
}
```

**essensplan.component.ts**

```
getEssensplan(): void {
    this.essensplanService.getEssensplan()
        .subscribe(essensplan => this.essensplan = essensplan);
}
```

**essensplan.component.html**

```html
<ul class="essensplan">
    <li *ngFor="let essensplan of essensplan">
        <span class="badge">{{essensplan.wochennummer}}</span> 
        {{essensplan.essenProWoche}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result is, that it just shows the bullet points for 8 different objects of the array, but no details. Do you maybe know, where the error is? Important is that in "fetches essensplan".

Comment: Try this.. {{essensplan.essenProWoche | json}}

Comment: it did not work :/ @FintanKearney

Comment: What value you are getting in this.essensplanService.getEssensplan()
  .subscribe(essensplan => this.essensplan = essensplan);
}
its a proper value just print it in console and check

Comment: See below answer. You are not referencing .EssenProWoche in your ng-repeat

Comment: @FintanKearney It seems you are right

Comment: @SiddharthJain ahh, now i see a problem. it says "undefined" in console.

Comment: @Ascena try Fintan suggestion it will work  as you are running for each  of essensplan.EssenProWoche so it may return undefined

Comment: @SiddharthJain it did not work, got this error: EssensplanComponent.html:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'EssenProWoche' of undefined

Comment: Just comment html code and 
please provide output  of 
 this.essensplanService.getEssensplan()
        .subscribe(essensplan => (console.log(essensplan));

Comment: @SiddharthJain - output is: undefined.

Comment: @Ascena then there is wrong in your service as this is  not returning data 
getEssensplan(): Observable<Essensplan[]> {
    return this.http.get<Essensplan[]>(this.essensplanUrl)
        .pipe(
            tap(essensplanUrl => this.log('fetched essensplan')),
            catchError(this.handleError('getEssensplan', []))
        );
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are referencing keys starting with a lowercase letter (wochennummer, essenProWoche) within the template, while in the actual data structure contains keys starting with capital letters (Wochennummer, EssenProWoche). Thats why the template doesnt know these properties.

Try to stay consistent with your property names, i suggest to use CamelCase starting with lowercase letters. But of course its your decision.

Another advice, look into async in order to avoid having a local var like essensplan. It reduces boilerplate.

data:

```
"essensPlan": [{
 "wochenNummer": 1,
 "essenProWoche": [
   11,
   12, 
   13
 ], 
},//...]
```

controller:

```
// further up define essensPlan$ as Observable<Essensplan[]>
essensPlan$ = this.essensplanService.getEssensplan();
```

template;

```
<li *ngFor="let essensPlanItem of essensPlan$ | async">
     <span class="badge">{{essensPlanItem.wochenNummer}}</span>
</li>
```

Furthermore I think your classes are actually interfaces; new-ing EssenProWoche with new Array(5) is not necessary.

Comment: I think you're right: imho the part ``subscribe(essensplan => this.essensplan = essensplan)`` causes trouble, because the local `essensplan` is the same as `this.essensplan`. Try to avoid local variables and use async instead.

Comment: @mareks - we found the problem and you helped us with the advice to rename everything. it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul class="essensplan">
    <li *ngFor="let essensplan of essensplan.EssenProWoche">
        <span class="badge">{{essensplan.wochennummer}}</span>
        {{essensplan}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: console says: EssensplanComponent.html:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 
 'EssenProWoche' of undefined

Comment: Could you add an explanation of this code, since it's not clear if/how it solves the problem? Thanks!